# How can I pass isAuthenticated to let Authenticated Component route to protected route?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-router-v4

I'm implementing protected route by react router v4.
I'm trying to pass "isAuthenticated" value from "Login" Component to "Authenticated" Component but I get "false" value.

Maybe I use the wrong way, Could anybody please help to fix this problem?

My code as following:

Login.js provide "isAuthenticated" control

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from '../constants';
import { USERNAME } from '../constants';
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { Row, Col, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const Auth = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    // setTimeout(cb, 100);
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    // setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  };

    login = () => {
        Auth.authenticate();
        console.log(Auth.isAuthenticated);
    };

  render() {

    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={5} lg={4}>
                    <div className="Login">
                <h4 className="page-header">Login</h4>
                  <form ref={form => (this.form = form)} onSubmit={event => event.preventDefault()}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Username</ControlLabel>
                        <br />
                    <input
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
                          type="text"
                          autoFocus
                      />
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
                        <br/>
                        <input
                            value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                            type="password"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      <div onClick={() => {this._confirm(); this.login(); }}>
                          <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success">Login</Button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
  )
};

  _confirm = async () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

      const result = await this.props.loginMutation({
        variables: {
          username,
          password,
        },
      });

      const { token } = result;
      this._saveUserData(token, username);

        this.props.history.push(`/`);
  }

  _saveUserData = (token, username) => {
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token);
    localStorage.setItem(USERNAME, username);
  }
};

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LoginMutation($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    loginMutation(username: $username, password: $password) {
      token
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(
  graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION, { name: 'loginMutation' }),
)(Login);
```

Authenticated.js need to get "isAuthenticated" value (true) to render the protected route.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth } from '../pages/Login';

console.log(Auth.isAuthenticated);

class Authenticated extends Component {
  render() {
        const {
            component: Component, exact, ...rest
        } = this.props;

        return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            exact={exact}
            render={props => (
            Auth.isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component { ...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
        ))}
        />
        );
    }
}



export default Authenticated;
```

=== Workaround Solution ===

Authenticated.js -> get the value from localStorage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AUTH_TOKEN, IS_AUTHEN } from '../constants';

class Authenticated extends Component {


  render() {
        const {
            component: Component, exact, ...rest
        } = this.props;
        const isAuthenticated = !!localStorage.getItem(IS_AUTHEN) && !!localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
        console.log(isAuthenticated);

        return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            exact={exact}
            render={props => (
            isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component { ...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
        ))}
        />
        );
    }
}



export default Authenticated;
```

Login.js -> Store value by using localStorage.setItem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AUTH_TOKEN, USERNAME, IS_AUTHEN } from '../constants';
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { Row, Col, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    authenticated: false,
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={5} lg={4}>
                    <div className="Login">
                <h4 className="page-header">Login</h4>
                  <form ref={form => (this.form = form)} onSubmit={event => event.preventDefault()}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Username</ControlLabel>
                        <br />
                    <input
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
                          type="text"
                          autoFocus
                      />
                    </FormGroup>

                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
                        <br/>
                        <input
                            value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                            type="password"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      <div onClick={() => this._confirm()}>
                          <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success">Login</Button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
  )
};

  _confirm = async () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

      const result = await this.props.loginMutation({
        variables: {
          username,
          password,
        },
      });

      this.setState({ authenticated: true });
      const { token } = result;
      this._saveUserData(token, username, this.state.authenticated);

        this.props.history.push(`/channel`);
  }

  _saveUserData = (token, username, authenticated) => {
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token);
    localStorage.setItem(USERNAME, username);
    localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHEN, authenticated);
  }
};

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LoginMutation($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    loginMutation(username: $username, password: $password) {
      token
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(
  graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION, { name: 'loginMutation' }),
)(Login);
```

Comment: Auth is imported in the beginning, its imported as false. Are you sure that isAuthenticated is true on componentMount of Authenticated?

Comment: Hi Chaitanya, thank you very much for your guide, I have the workaround solution by using localStorage.  
But I'm not sure that is there any security concern...
If I use react lifecycle by checking componentMount, how could I do that.
Could you please share? (Note: I update my solution in my question)

Comment: saving token in LocalStorage is not much harmful. but, saving is_auth in local is not recommended. Ill share you some code in a while(code that i implemented for auth). Please give me a couple of hours

Comment: Chaitanya, Thank you very much!!

Comment: Posted my answer below, sorry for being late :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, On the beginning of the app(index.js), I check for token and set is_auth in my state, like this

```
<!-- ls is LocalStorageService for get and set from localStorage-->

    if (ls.getUserDetails() && ls.getUserDetails().roles && ls.getUserDetails().roles.length) {
      store.dispatch({ type: SET_USER_ROLE, role: ls.getUserDetails().roles[0] });
      if (ls.getToken()) {
        store.dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE_USER, auth: true });
      }
    }
    else {
      store.dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE_USER, auth: false });
    }
```

Then, I made an AuthGuard to validate login status, (by mapping state's auth to this class's props)

AuthGuard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { store } from '../stores/configureStore';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {

    // If user not authenticated render out to root

    class AuthGuard extends Component {
        static contextTypes = {
            router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        };

        componentWillMount() {
            if (!this.props.authenticated) {
                //hashHistory.push('#/login');
                store.dispatch(push('/login'));
            }
        }

        componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
            if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
                //hashHistory.push('#/login');
                store.dispatch(push('/login'));
            }
        }

        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        authenticated: state.auth.auth
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthGuard);
}
```

And then in my App.js, where I do my routing,

App.js

```
<!--PROTECTED ROUTES GO AFTER '/app/'-->
        <Route path={`${match.url}app`} component={authGuard(MainApp)} /> 

<!--UNPROTECTED ROUTES GO AFTER '/' LIKE BELOW-->
        <Route exact path="/404" component={Page404} />
        <Route exact path="/403" component={Page403} />
        <Route exact path="/500" component={Page500} />
        <Route exact path="/confirm-email" component={PageConfirmEmail} />
        <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={PageForgotPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/fullscreen" component={PageFullscreen} />
        <Route exact path="/lock-screen" component={PageLockScreen} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={PageLogin} />
        <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={PageSignUp} />
```

Comment below, for any questions :)